# Premier Pro CS5 makes AVCHD footage jagged and bad

Tags: premiere, video-quality, avchd

I'm shooting on an FS700RH, the quality is fantastic when I preview it after putting it on my computer, but when I import it into Premiere, the quality just drops every time. I've tried multiple solutions, importing it different ways other than the Media Browser, changing the project settings and so on but I have no luck. The results are always the same. Horrible Jagged edges.

Footage before importing to Premiere:

[image]

Footage after importing to Premiere:

[image]

This is also how it looks after exporting as well so it's not just a problem with the Source Monitor. Like importing I've tried many different export settings, all with the same result. I have no idea what to do in order to preserve the quality.

I've spent the past 3 hours trying to find a solution online but have had no luck.

Comment: 1) Are you interpreting it as interlaced or progressive? 2) Can you attached Mediainfo output for the file?

Comment: I've literally just fixed it! I right clicked it went to Modify -> Interperite -> Changes Upper Field to Progressive Scan in the Field Order. Never knew that option was there! Thanks fella if that was your thought in the first place haha!

Comment: Yes, that's what it looked like.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted the answer incase anyone else comes by this problem. From those hours no one suggested that at all. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone comes across the same problem, here's the solution I used.

Once you've imported the footage, right click on the clip, go to 'Modify' then 'Interpret Footage':

[image]

A window should pop up. Down the bottom, under 'Field Order' change the setting from 'Upper Field First' to 'Conform to: No Fields (Progressive Scan)'.

[image]

Your footage should then adjust to it's original quality.

Upper Field First:

[image]

No Fields (Progressive Scan):

[image]